# Can I Request the Latest Package with a specific Pre-Release Tag?

Tags: chocolatey

I work in an environment in which we have to distribute multiple different pre-release versions of our packages to internal employees who are not developers.  I'm giving them a .bat file right now that has the "-pre" flag, to install the latest pre-release version.  However, i'm now finding that I need both a "beta" pre-release as well as an "alpha" that can each evolve independently.

I know I can explicitly specify the exact version I need, but is there a way to get the latest "alpha" version of my package and then also get the latest "beta" version, while overlooking any other versions?  As far as I can tell, this is not possible, but I want to see if anyone has any insight beyond my experience regarding this issue.

*If* Chocolatey can handle what I'm describing, then I'd be able to give our employees a .bat file for installing whatever the latest "alpha" version is, as well as one for installing the latest "beta" version.
Here's an example of what I'm thinking as far as how this *could* look:

```
choco install mypackagename -pre alpha
```

and

```
choco install mypackagename -pre beta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `-pre` will only get you the latest prerelease. One thing you could do though is use an exact version to install those prereleases.